# Python Pandas date time stamp X-axis arrange

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of daily part forecasts which we merge into a single CSV file and been using Pandas for ages, but I am really stuck how to resolve this problem. We merge the part forecast into a single csv as below, first two columns are the part reference and date when we created the forecast, this can be used to filter parts and dates.  The remaining columns are the part forecast with date on the top column and the the part volumes in the remaining cells.

The problem is the Date (first top row), dates are not in order due to how the part forecast been generated and I would like to sort out the date which means Pandas arranging the date in the X-axis.

What is really odd is the DF looks okay, Pandas has split up the date and I have row clearly defined as timestamp, but I cannot seem to find a way to arrange these columns into correct order

[image]

```
Part Number Ref,Date,2023-08-13 00:00:00,2023-08-20 00:00:00,2023-08-27 00:00:00,2023-09-03 00:00:00,2023-09-10 00:00:00,2023-09-17 00:00:00,2023-09-24 00:00:00,2023-10-01 00:00:00,2023-11-01 00:00:00,2023-12-01 00:00:00,2024-01-01 00:00:00,2024-02-01 00:00:00,2023-07-09 00:00:00,2023-07-16 00:00:00,2023-07-23 00:00:00,2023-07-30 00:00:00,2023-08-06 00:00:00,2023-09-01 00:00:00,2023-07-02 00:00:00
    part ref A,16Aug2023,0.0,0.0,155.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
    part ref B,16Aug2023,200.0,200.0,114.0,202.0,200.0,200.0,200.0,1014,800,630,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
    part ref A,18Aug2023,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
    part ref C,10July2023,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

I have tried different methods to sort out the X-axis timestamp, the problem is Pandas normally formats in the Y-axis.  Also another problem is the code is deleting the first row and thinks the date in the row 1.  I have removed the first two columns, then what to arrange the date order (oldest to newest).

Not sure if I need to transpose all the date into the Y axis sort then switch back to the original format.  The problems are:

1. Pandas is ignoring the first row
2. How to sort the x-axis date stamp using the row called "date" in oldest to newest
3. Retain the format of the CSV, as this is loaded into Excel

```py
import pandas as pd

# Load the CSV into a DataFrame
csv_file_path = 'combined_output_filled.csv' 

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, index_col=0)

# Drop the first two columns
df = df.iloc[:, 2:]

print(df)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df_transposed = df.T

df_transposed.columns = df_transposed.iloc[0]

df_transposed = df_transposed[1:]

df_transposed.index = pd.to_datetime(df_transposed.index, dayfirst=True)

df_transposed = df_transposed.reindex(sorted(df_transposed.columns), axis=1)

sorted_csv_file_path = 'sorted_file.csv'  
df_transposed.to_csv(sorted_csv_file_path)

print("Transposed and sorted DataFrame saved to", sorted_csv_file_path)
```

Comment: I manage to get this working by converting the timestamps into a unix format then use the sort function to order the dates in the rows.  Bit of a hack around, but it works might look for a neater way to make it work in the future.